# GCM for Android 2

Tags: php, android, google-play-services, google-cloud-messaging

I follow this tutorial [enter link description here](http://www.programming-techniques.com/2014/01/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-in-android.html) When I run my apps and click register button but not save registration id in db. I am using local host. I change my Sender id, and create project and give SHA1 key and project name. But what's problem when I am doing register it's does not save db in register id. And show this message in logcat. Thanks Advance!!

```
11-01 19:21:35.542: I/CheckinService(1506): Done disabling old GoogleServicesFramework version
11-01 19:21:36.082: I/MultiDex(1785): VM with version 1.6.0 does not have multidex support
11-01 19:21:36.092: I/MultiDex(1785): install
11-01 19:21:36.192: I/MultiDex(1785): MultiDexExtractor.load(/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk, false)
11-01 19:21:36.232: I/MultiDex(1785): loading existing secondary dex files
11-01 19:21:36.232: I/MultiDex(1785): load found 2 secondary dex files
11-01 19:21:36.262: I/MultiDex(1785): install done
11-01 19:21:36.732: I/ProviderInstaller(1785): Insert disabled by gate 'gms:security:enable_conscrypt_in_gms_application'
11-01 19:21:38.282: I/GoogleHttpClient(1785): Falling back to old SSLCertificateSocketFactory
11-01 19:21:39.252: D/dalvikvm(1785): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 287K, 11% free 2878K/3220K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
11-01 19:21:42.182: D/dalvikvm(1785): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 402K, 14% free 2982K/3444K, paused 90ms, total 90ms
11-01 19:21:43.622: D/dalvikvm(1785): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 240K, 9% free 3250K/3548K, paused 153ms, total 153ms
11-01 19:21:44.762: D/dalvikvm(1785): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_dg_cache/5F827D5013CA6C4C435C4FFD08AC5DB6C890250F/lib/libdroidguard_661B0743C3F6A112262CE0DBD5BAAC146F5FB00F.so 0xb1fc70f8
11-01 19:21:44.762: D/dalvikvm(1785): Added shared lib /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_dg_cache/5F827D5013CA6C4C435C4FFD08AC5DB6C890250F/lib/libdroidguard_661B0743C3F6A112262CE0DBD5BAAC146F5FB00F.so 0xb1fc70f8
11-01 19:21:44.762: D/dalvikvm(1785): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_dg_cache/5F827D5013CA6C4C435C4FFD08AC5DB6C890250F/lib/libdroidguard_661B0743C3F6A112262CE0DBD5BAAC146F5FB00F.so 0xb1fc70f8, skipping init
11-01 19:21:47.082: W/ActivityThread(1506): ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
11-01 19:21:49.812: D/dalvikvm(1506): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 416K, 13% free 3321K/3792K, paused 39ms, total 39ms
11-01 19:21:49.842: I/EventLogService(1506): Aggregate from 1414884080761 (log), 1414835566690 (data)
11-01 19:21:49.872: I/SystemUpdateService(1506): receiver: Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED flg=0x8000010 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.update.SystemUpdateService$Receiver (has extras) }
11-01 19:21:49.912: D/SystemUpdateService(1506): onCreate
11-01 19:21:49.962: D/SystemUpdateService(1506): onStartCommand: intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.update.SystemUpdateService (has extras) }
11-01 19:21:49.972: I/dalvikvm(1506): Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setColor, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.update.o.a
11-01 19:21:49.972: W/dalvikvm(1506): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 224: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setColor (I)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
11-01 19:21:49.972: D/dalvikvm(1506): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00a9
11-01 19:21:49.992: I/dalvikvm(1506): Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setCategory, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.update.o.a
11-01 19:21:49.992: W/dalvikvm(1506): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 223: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setCategory (Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
11-01 19:21:49.992: D/dalvikvm(1506): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0679
11-01 19:21:50.022: I/ConfigFetchService(1506): PackageReceiver: Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED flg=0x8000010 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.config.ConfigFetchService$PackageReceiver (has extras) }
11-01 19:21:50.272: I/ConfigFetchService(1506): onStartCommand Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED cmp=com.google.android.gms/.config.ConfigFetchService (has extras) }
11-01 19:21:50.282: I/ConfigFetchService(1506): launchTask
11-01 19:21:50.292: I/SystemUpdateService(1506): cancelUpdate (empty URL)
11-01 19:21:50.292: I/SystemUpdateService(1506): active receiver: disabled
11-01 19:21:50.402: I/ConfigFetchService(1506): service connected
11-01 19:21:50.422: I/ConfigClient(1506): service connected
11-01 19:21:50.432: I/ConfigFetchService(1506): connected = true
11-01 19:21:50.442: I/ConfigFetchService(1506): self-hosted config:fetch_interval = 43200
11-01 19:21:50.722: D/dalvikvm(1506): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 464K, 14% free 3369K/3888K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
11-01 19:21:50.732: I/CheckinTask(1506): Sending checkin request (1615 bytes)
11-01 19:21:51.002: D/SystemUpdateService(1506): onDestroy
11-01 19:21:51.062: E/CheckinTask(1506): Checkin failed: https://android.clients.google.com/checkin (request #0): java.io.IOException: Rejected response from server: bad security token
11-01 19:21:51.092: D/GCM(1506): COMPAT: Multi user not supported
11-01 19:21:51.252: V/AuthZen(1506): Handling intent: android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
11-01 19:21:51.322: V/AuthZen(1506): [DefaultAuthzenGcmReceiverDelegateService] Handling delegate intent.
11-01 19:21:51.482: I/GCoreUlr(1506): Starting service, intent=Intent { act=com.google.android.location.reporting.ACTION_UPDATE_WORLD cmp=com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.reporting.service.DispatchingService (has extras) }, extras=Bundle[{receiverAction=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED}]
11-01 19:21:51.792: I/CheckinService(1506): active receiver: disabled
11-01 19:21:52.012: D/dalvikvm(1506): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 425K, 13% free 3456K/3936K, paused 106ms, total 106ms
11-01 19:21:52.062: I/AuthZen(1506): Fetching signing key...
11-01 19:21:52.162: E/StrictMode(1506): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
11-01 19:21:52.162: E/StrictMode(1506): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
11-01 19:21:52.162: E/StrictMode(1506):     at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
11-01 19:21:52.162: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:278)
11-01 19:21:52.162: E/StrictMode(1506):     at android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:190)
11-01 19:21:52.162: E/StrictMode(1506):     at android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:435)
11-01 19:21:52.162: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:131)
11-01 19:21:52.162: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:107)
11-01 19:21:52.162: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
11-01 19:21:52.162: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
11-01 19:21:52.162: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
11-01 19:21:52.162: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
11-01 19:21:52.162: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
11-01 19:21:52.162: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
11-01 19:21:52.162: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
11-01 19:21:52.162: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.google.android.gms.checkin.f.a(SourceFile:302)
11-01 19:21:52.162: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.google.android.gms.checkin.f.a(SourceFile:210)
11-01 19:21:52.162: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.google.android.gms.checkin.c.a(SourceFile:375)
11-01 19:21:52.162: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.google.android.gms.checkin.c.doInBackground(SourceFile:365)
11-01 19:21:52.162: E/StrictMode(1506):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
11-01 19:21:52.162: E/StrictMode(1506):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-01 19:21:52.162: E/StrictMode(1506):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-01 19:21:52.292: I/AuthZen(1506): Signing key fetched successfuly!
11-01 19:21:52.302: D/dalvikvm(1506): No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libAppDataSearch.so 0xb1f90440, skipping init
11-01 19:22:00.472: I/GoogleHttpClient(1506): Falling back to old SSLCertificateSocketFactory
11-01 19:22:00.852: I/ConfigFetchService(1506): fetch service done; releasing wakelock
11-01 19:22:00.852: I/ConfigFetchService(1506): stopping self
11-01 19:22:11.002: D/dalvikvm(1506): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 474K, 14% free 3494K/4024K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
11-01 19:22:12.332: D/dalvikvm(1506): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 512K, 15% free 3494K/4064K, paused 98ms, total 98ms
11-01 19:22:13.562: I/CheckinService(1506): active receiver: enabled
11-01 19:22:13.602: I/CheckinService(1506): Preparing to send checkin request
11-01 19:22:13.622: I/EventLogService(1506): Accumulating logs since 1414884109869
11-01 19:22:13.682: I/GoogleHttpClient(1506): Falling back to old SSLCertificateSocketFactory
11-01 06:21:31.819: D/PackageBroadcastService(1506): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED and uri=com.google.android.gms
11-01 06:21:31.829: I/PackageBroadcastService(1506): Null package name or gms related package.  Ignoreing.
11-01 06:21:31.939: I/ConfigFetchService(1506): PackageReceiver: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.example.gcmserver flg=0x4000010 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.config.ConfigFetchService$PackageReceiver (has extras) }
11-01 06:21:32.129: D/dalvikvm(1506): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 503K, 14% free 3503K/4064K, paused 109ms, total 109ms
11-01 06:21:32.169: I/ConfigFetchService(1506): onStartCommand Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:com.example.gcmserver cmp=com.google.android.gms/.config.ConfigFetchService (has extras) }
11-01 06:21:32.309: I/GoogleHttpClient(1506): Falling back to old SSLCertificateSocketFactory
11-01 06:21:32.489: I/ConfigFetchService(1506): service connected
11-01 06:21:32.489: I/ConfigClient(1506): service connected
11-01 06:21:32.559: D/PackageBroadcastService(1506): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED and uri=com.example.gcmserver
11-01 06:21:32.809: I/Icing(1506): Storage manager: low false usage 56.14KB avail 389.84MB capacity 460.89MB
11-01 06:21:33.059: I/ConfigFetchService(1506): PackageReceiver: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.example.gcmserver flg=0x4000010 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.config.ConfigFetchService$PackageReceiver (has extras) }
11-01 06:21:33.209: I/ConfigFetchService(1506): onStartCommand Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.example.gcmserver cmp=com.google.android.gms/.config.ConfigFetchService (has extras) }
11-01 06:21:33.209: I/ConfigFetchService(1506): launchTask
11-01 06:21:33.249: I/MultiDex(2056): VM with version 1.6.0 does not have multidex support
11-01 06:21:33.269: I/MultiDex(2056): install
11-01 06:21:33.279: I/MultiDex(2056): MultiDexExtractor.load(/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk, false)
11-01 06:21:33.299: I/ConfigFetchService(1506): service connected
11-01 06:21:33.309: I/ConfigClient(1506): service connected
11-01 06:21:33.359: D/PackageBroadcastService(1506): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=com.example.gcmserver
11-01 06:21:33.369: I/MultiDex(2056): loading existing secondary dex files
11-01 06:21:33.379: I/MultiDex(2056): load found 2 secondary dex files
11-01 06:21:33.409: I/MultiDex(2056): install done
11-01 06:21:33.589: I/ProviderInstaller(2056): Insert disabled by gate 'gms:security:enable_conscrypt_in_gms_application'
11-01 06:21:34.379: I/GoogleHttpClient(1506): Falling back to old SSLCertificateSocketFactory
11-01 06:21:34.379: D/dalvikvm(1506): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 343K, 12% free 3613K/4064K, paused 235ms, total 235ms
11-01 06:21:34.509: D/PackageBroadcastService(1506): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED and uri=com.example.gcmserver
11-01 06:21:34.749: I/GoogleHttpClient(2056): Falling back to old SSLCertificateSocketFactory
11-01 06:21:34.909: W/GmsApplication(1506): Using Auth Proxy for data requests.
11-01 06:21:35.089: I/GoogleHttpClient(1506): Falling back to old SSLCertificateSocketFactory
11-01 06:21:35.099: D/dalvikvm(2056): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 286K, 11% free 2879K/3220K, paused 103ms, total 104ms
11-01 06:21:35.109: I/GLSUser(1506): [ ChannelManager ] Attempting to channel bind connection HttpClient.
11-01 06:21:35.319: I/GLSUser(1506): [ ChannelManager ] Skip channel binding on pre-KLP devices.
11-01 06:21:35.369: I/PeopleContactsSync(1506): CP2 sync disabled
11-01 06:21:35.429: W/dalvikvm(1506): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/app/SharedElementCallback;)
11-01 06:21:35.429: I/dalvikvm(1506): Could not find method android.app.Activity.setEnterSharedElementCallback, referenced from method android.support.v4.app.q.setEnterSharedElementCallback
11-01 06:21:35.429: W/dalvikvm(1506): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 75: Landroid/app/Activity;.setEnterSharedElementCallback (Landroid/app/SharedElementCallback;)V
11-01 06:21:35.429: D/dalvikvm(1506): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
11-01 06:21:35.439: W/GmsApplication(1506): Using Auth Proxy for data requests.
11-01 06:21:35.449: W/dalvikvm(1506): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/app/SharedElementCallback;)
11-01 06:21:35.449: I/dalvikvm(1506): Could not find method android.app.Activity.setExitSharedElementCallback, referenced from method android.support.v4.app.q.setExitSharedElementCallback
11-01 06:21:35.449: W/dalvikvm(1506): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 76: Landroid/app/Activity;.setExitSharedElementCallback (Landroid/app/SharedElementCallback;)V
11-01 06:21:35.449: D/dalvikvm(1506): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
11-01 06:21:35.449: I/dalvikvm(1506): Could not find method android.app.Activity.finishAfterTransition, referenced from method android.support.v4.app.q.supportFinishAfterTransition
11-01 06:21:35.449: W/dalvikvm(1506): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 39: Landroid/app/Activity;.finishAfterTransition ()V
11-01 06:21:35.449: D/dalvikvm(1506): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
11-01 06:21:35.459: I/dalvikvm(1506): Could not find method android.app.Activity.postponeEnterTransition, referenced from method android.support.v4.app.q.supportPostponeEnterTransition
11-01 06:21:35.459: W/dalvikvm(1506): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 71: Landroid/app/Activity;.postponeEnterTransition ()V
11-01 06:21:35.459: D/dalvikvm(1506): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
11-01 06:21:35.459: I/dalvikvm(1506): Could not find method android.app.Activity.startPostponedEnterTransition, referenced from method android.support.v4.app.q.supportStartPostponedEnterTransition
11-01 06:21:35.459: W/dalvikvm(1506): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 84: Landroid/app/Activity;.startPostponedEnterTransition ()V
11-01 06:21:35.459: D/dalvikvm(1506): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
11-01 06:21:35.639: W/GmsApplication(1506): Using Auth Proxy for data requests.
11-01 06:21:35.709: W/GmsApplication(1506): Using Auth Proxy for data requests.
11-01 06:21:35.739: W/GmsApplication(1506): Using Auth Proxy for data requests.
11-01 06:21:35.779: W/GmsApplication(1506): Using Auth Proxy for data requests.
11-01 06:21:36.019: D/dalvikvm(1506): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 349K, 10% free 3776K/4180K, paused 77ms, total 77ms
11-01 06:21:36.769: I/ConfigFetchService(1506): fetch service done; releasing wakelock
11-01 06:21:36.769: I/ConfigFetchService(1506): stopping self
11-01 06:21:36.809: D/dalvikvm(2056): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 340K, 12% free 3053K/3448K, paused 79ms, total 79ms
11-01 06:21:37.589: D/dalvikvm(2056): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 148K, 6% free 3409K/3620K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
11-01 06:21:37.979: D/dalvikvm(2056): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_dg_cache/5F827D5013CA6C4C435C4FFD08AC5DB6C890250F/lib/libdroidguard_661B0743C3F6A112262CE0DBD5BAAC146F5FB00F.so 0xb20132b8
11-01 06:21:37.989: D/dalvikvm(2056): Added shared lib /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_dg_cache/5F827D5013CA6C4C435C4FFD08AC5DB6C890250F/lib/libdroidguard_661B0743C3F6A112262CE0DBD5BAAC146F5FB00F.so 0xb20132b8
11-01 06:21:37.989: D/dalvikvm(2056): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_dg_cache/5F827D5013CA6C4C435C4FFD08AC5DB6C890250F/lib/libdroidguard_661B0743C3F6A112262CE0DBD5BAAC146F5FB00F.so 0xb20132b8, skipping init
11-01 06:21:38.129: E/Icing(1506): Could not mmap file for reading: Invalid argument
11-01 06:21:38.339: D/dalvikvm(1506): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 432K, 12% free 3857K/4344K, paused 119ms, total 119ms
11-01 06:21:38.599: I/Icing(1506): updateResources: need to parse e{com.google.android.gms}
11-01 06:21:38.689: I/CheckinTask(1506): Sending checkin request (1650 bytes)
11-01 06:21:38.799: I/Icing(1506): Internal init done: storage state 0
11-01 06:21:38.809: E/CheckinTask(1506): Checkin failed: https://android.clients.google.com/checkin (request #0): java.io.IOException: Rejected response from server: bad security token
11-01 06:21:38.869: I/CheckinService(1506): active receiver: disabled
11-01 06:21:38.919: I/Icing(1506): Post-init done
11-01 06:21:38.949: I/CheckinService(1506): active receiver: disabled
11-01 06:21:38.989: I/Icing(1506): updateResources: need to parse e{com.google.android.gms}
11-01 06:21:55.969: D/dalvikvm(1506): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 480K, 13% free 3878K/4420K, paused 208ms, total 208ms
11-01 06:21:56.049: E/StrictMode(1506): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
11-01 06:21:56.049: E/StrictMode(1506): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
11-01 06:21:56.049: E/StrictMode(1506):     at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
11-01 06:21:56.049: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:278)
11-01 06:21:56.049: E/StrictMode(1506):     at android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:190)
11-01 06:21:56.049: E/StrictMode(1506):     at android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:435)
11-01 06:21:56.049: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:131)
11-01 06:21:56.049: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:107)
11-01 06:21:56.049: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
11-01 06:21:56.049: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
11-01 06:21:56.049: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
11-01 06:21:56.049: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
11-01 06:21:56.049: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
11-01 06:21:56.049: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
11-01 06:21:56.049: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
11-01 06:21:56.049: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.google.android.gms.checkin.f.a(SourceFile:302)
11-01 06:21:56.049: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.google.android.gms.checkin.f.a(SourceFile:210)
11-01 06:21:56.049: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.google.android.gms.checkin.c.a(SourceFile:375)
11-01 06:21:56.049: E/StrictMode(1506):     at com.google.android.gms.checkin.c.doInBackground(SourceFile:365)
11-01 06:21:56.049: E/StrictMode(1506):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
11-01 06:21:56.049: E/StrictMode(1506):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-01 06:21:56.049: E/StrictMode(1506):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-01 06:21:56.659: I/CheckinService(1506): active receiver: disabled
11-01 06:21:56.849: D/PackageBroadcastService(1506): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED and uri=com.google.android.gms
11-01 06:21:56.849: I/PackageBroadcastService(1506): Null package name or gms related package.  Ignoreing.
11-01 06:21:57.119: I/Icing(1506): updateResources: need to parse e{com.google.android.gms}
11-01 06:21:57.569: I/CheckinService(1506): active receiver: disabled
11-01 06:21:58.739: D/PackageBroadcastService(1506): Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED and uri=com.google.android.gms
11-01 06:21:58.739: I/PackageBroadcastService(1506): Null package name or gms related package.  Ignoreing.
11-01 06:21:58.919: I/Icing(1506): updateResources: need to parse e{com.google.android.gms}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Error I just can suggest you follow official [tutorial about implementing GCM client](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html). You need be sure that you correct define GcmBroadCastReceiver, permissions and other things in your AndroidManifest.xml. Also you can try [my test push server](http://1-dot-sigma-freedom-752.appspot.com/) :)